# Why don't my images fill the screen when viewing on mobile device in portrait?

Tags: html, css, slider, image-scaling, mobile-devices

I have just inspected my website on mobile device, and it looks great in landscape. However the images only fill up half of the page when held in portrait mode. It also shrinks down my logo which is a problem too.

The images are being displayed in a slider which I have created on HTML & CSS.

I am also using bootstrap 4, however I also had this problem before I'd added the bootstrap into my code.

Please see below x2 images of how it currently looks on mobile & x1 image of how I'd like it too look in portrait.

[PORTRAIT - HOW IT CURRENTLY LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENf8A.png)

[LANDSCAPE - HOW IT CURRENTLY LOOKS (happy with this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyUgs.png)

[PORTRAIT - HOW I WOULD LIKE IT TO SIT ON SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ye0.png)

I have tried:

- Setting the width/height to 100% in CSS
- Adding a viewport meta tag to stop it scaling on mobile devices
- Changing the height of my scroller with the @media tag (so it doesn't affect desktop viewing)

Please see below current HTML & CSS.

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
<style>

      /* hide mobile version by default */
  .my-navbar .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  /* when screen is less than 600px wide
     show mobile version and hide desktop */
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo .mobile {
      display: block;
    }
    .logo .desktop {
      display: none;
    }
  }

</style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title> shannonkelseyann</title>

    </head>

<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="../websitehtml/images/white-heart.png"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.html"><img class="home" src="https://i.imgur.com/c2UQ8om.png"></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="campaign.html"><img class="campaign" src="https://i.imgur.com/cQE71uK.png"></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="e-commerce.html"><img class="e-commerce" src="https://i.imgur.com/01tEvO3.png"></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="info.html"><img class="info" src="https://i.imgur.com/JjNQ54R.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class=logo>

  <img src="../websitehtml/images/desktoplogo1.png" class="desktop">
  <img src="../websitehtml/images/mobile-logo.png" class="mobile">
</div>



                <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/2.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/1.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/3.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-4"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/4.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-5"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-6"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/6.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-7"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/7.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-8"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/8.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-9"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/9.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-10"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/10.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-11"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/11.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-12"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/12.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-13"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/13.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-14"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/14.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-15"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/15.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-16"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/16.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide-17"><img class="tenerife-womens" src="../WEBSITEHTML/IMAGES/tenerife-WOMENS/17.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
                </div>

            </body>


        <footer><p style="text-align: center;">© 2020 by shannonkelseyann</footer></p>


</html>
```

CSS

```
    background-image: url(../WEBSITE/bluebackground.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #8DB6E4;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;

}


div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

footer {
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    float: center;

}

h2 {
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-top: 0px;

}

.row {
    padding: 5%;
}

.slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0px ;
}

.slider {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 650px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 11px ;
  padding: 0px ;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.slider {
  ...

  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}


.navbar {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;

}

.my-navbar {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;

}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be much appreciated.
Thank-you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these classes on your picture's parent `<div class="col-12>"` for a full width in screen <576px, `<div class="col-sm-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥576px, `<div class="col-md-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥768px, `<div class="col-lg-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥992px, `<div class="col-xl-12>`" for a full width in screen ≥1200px. Make sure that all of the pictures are in the same div so that they are responsive no matter what size of your display is and instead of using 12 for a full width, you can use 6 so that 2 pictures will be displayed in the same line. For more about column you can check here Bootstrap Grid System